# Javascript ascii http&#58;// regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How to match ascii with regex? ... I currently use this:

```
/(https?\:\/\/[^ ]*?)( |$)/gim
```

to match

- http://
- https://

but have recently noticed it not working due to ascii chars being added

now I need a regex to match

- http://
- https://

and/or

- `http&#58;//`

any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/(https?(:|&#58;)\/\/[^ ]*?)( |$)/gim`